# Updating the JTextfield from another class? [Java]

Tags: java, swing

I am very new to swing in Java and have the following problem:

I have a text field whose content should be changed, and when I add a mouse listener to another button for example to change the text, it is working:

```
private void charToggleMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO
    if (evt.getButton() == 1) {
        sendCommandField.setText("LOL This is working");
    }

}
```

But I want to change the text from another class in this case, so I created a setter for that (of course in the class where the text field is):

```
public void setCommandFieldText(String str) {
    sendCommandField.setText(str);
}
```

But it is not working. I setted the text that way from another class:

```
RemoteFrame frame = new RemoteFrame();
frame.setCommandFieldText("This should be in the text field now.");
```

I know that there are already thousands of questions of this topic but I got nothing work, and I hope you can help my anyway.

Comment: it will be good if you can share both class.

Comment: are you sure this another class is not called from separate thread?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

1. Store the new value in a static variable of the previous class in which you have that text box.
2. Then set that string value to the testfield in the class' constructor.

Comment: What? Static variable? Why the H?

Comment: Just an option. Class.variableName=value, can be helpful

Comment: This does not seem to help. I created a `system.out.println(sendCommandField.getText())` statement, and the result was: I saw the text in the console that I applied later, but nothing happend on my frame. So it seems that it has been applied but the frame/display needs to be updated?

Comment: or you can place it on a separate panel and then repaint that particular panel

Comment: Ok i have found the solution: In the class were the JFrame is, create a static method with a string for example as paramter and in the method body write for exanple frame.append(s);